# Write more than 4K bytes to exec.Cmd.StdinPipe()

Tags: go, process, pipe, ipc

### Problem

When writing data exceeding 4096 bytes to `Cmd.StdinPipe` in Go, program processing stops on Windows. This phenomenon does not occur when the same code running on Linux, or when writing process using goroutine.

### Question

Processing will not proceed from `_, err = in.Write ([] byte {'0'})` (4097 bytes) in the code shown below. Why is this?

Why does not it occur with goroutine or on Linux?

*** Golang reference describes Cmd.StdinPipe using goroutine as [an example](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdinPipe), and my problem has also been solved. This question arises from curiosity about Go.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("more")

    pype, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bytes4k := generateBytes(1024 * 4) // Works on Linux, but not Windows.
    // bytes4k := generateBytes(1024 * 64) // Don't works on Linux and Windows.
    fmt.Println("bytes generated.")

    // go writeBytes(pype, bytes4k) // Works fine!
    writeBytes(pype, bytes4k) // Can't write. Write is locked.

    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("finished.")
}

func generateBytes(num int) []byte {
    byte := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, num))
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        byte.WriteByte('0')
    }
    return byte.Bytes()
}

func writeBytes(in io.WriteCloser, bytes []byte) {
    defer in.Close()

    _, err := in.Write(bytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("written bytes to pipe.")

    _, err = in.Write([]byte{'0'}) // Why this code stops at 4097 bytes?
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("written 1 byte to pipe.")
}
```

#### Verified versions

- go version go1.10.1 windows/amd64
- go version go1.10.1 linux/amd64

Comment: It should be able to continue writing as soon as the `more` command reads more out of the pipe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing only blocks if no more space is in the pipe. While the size of the pipe in Windows might be 4k it is much larger in Linux. From [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html):

> ... Since Linux
>          2.6.11, the pipe capacity is 16 pages (i.e., **65,536 bytes** in a system
>          with a page size of 4096 bytes)...

Thus, you will probably get the same result on Linux as on Windows when writing into a pipe where nobody is reading but you need to write way more data into the pipe until you reach this situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I understood why above code does not work well on Windows.
And the reason  why works fine with goroutine is that it is read before pipe is full.

I tried writing 65536 bytes on Linux, then that program stopped, as you say!

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered, here's the workaround you'd probably want to use if you run into this issue - use the buffered writer instead, available in the [bufio](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio) package. This lets you wrap a writer with a larger buffer that you have full control over.

Comment: Or rather than buffering it twice, you write it from within in a goroutine as shown in the documentation

Comment: Yeah, I've used both methods. If you have a large number of writers, or if you're writing multiple times, it can be difficult to manage a goroutine per writer - writing in a goroutine can give rise to race conditions if you do that more than once quickly. At which point you need to move to a channel instead. Buffers are sometimes simpler.